# How to choose something like a pair from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and to Pandas. So I have the following scenario. 
The dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
  col1  col2  col3 col4 col5 col6 
0 x1    y1    z1   f1   e1   g1
1 x2    y2    z2   f2   e2   g2
```

The existing code is like the following:

```
items = set()
...
for item in df['col3'].tolist():
  if item not in items:
    items.add(item)
```

The "items" set is written to a file. Currently the output file contains just one column... "col3" something like this.

File: items.txt

```
col3
z1
z2
```

The new requirement is to write col3 and col5 in a file. Now the additional requirement is that `col5` value also needs to be captured for the corresponding `col3` value.

File: items.txt

```
col3    col5
z1      e1
z2      e2
```

I tried creating creating another `dataframe` with the following:

```
df1 = df[['col3', 'col5']]
```

but beyond this I am lost currently.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Anoop

Comment: Could you provide the output you are trying to get for your dataframe df please? That would help us answering you.

Comment: IIUC `items = {*df.col3, *df.col5}`

Comment: The "items" set is written to a file. Currently the output file contains just one column... "col3". The new requirement is to write col3 and col5 in a file. I shall edit the question to reflect the same.

Comment: Or do you need something like `list(zip(df.col3, df.col5))` --> `[('z1', 'e1'), ('z2', 'e2')]`

Comment: list(zip(df.col3, df.col5)) --> This is something I think I can work with, albeit inefficiently knowing my skills on python are rather naive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer to select for unique values. First we zip the 2 columns and find unique values with example df where I just duplicated rows from first df:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
x1      y1      z1      f1      e1      g1
x2      y2      z2      f2      e2      g2  
x1      y1      z1      f1      e1      g1
x2      y2      z2      f2      e2      g2
```

Then the code to get unique values of col3 with corresponding col5 values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/funky.csv')

df2 = df[['col3', 'col5']] # create new df of only col3 and col5
df_uniq = df2.drop_duplicates(['col3']) # keep only unique values of col3 and corresponding col5 values
df_uniq.to_csv('items.txt', sep='\t') # write to file
```

Comment: Thanks. The part you missed is that I need unique values of col3.

Comment: Sorry! I missed the unique part. The code has been updated to reflect the answer to your question.

Comment: updated the answer to be much simpler and more efficient because no iteration required!